# How to import several files with the same name from different folders into R?

Tags: r

So, I saw some posts but none of them match what I need.

Basically let's say I have a path like `C:\User\Files\` and within `Files` I have three folders `Data1`, `Data2` and `Data3`. Within each of the `Data` folders I have two `.csv` files that are named the same `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`. How can I import these two files from each of the folders in a loop separately? I used `list.files` but that combines all the `file1.csv`'s into one file and `file2.csv`'s into another file. I want to do a separate analysis on the different files.

What I tried for now is:

```
files1 <- list.files(path = "C:\\User\\Files\\",
                    pattern = "file1.csv", 
                    recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
files2 <- list.files(path = "C:\\User\Files\\",
                    pattern = "file2.csv", 
                    recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

But this combines all the `file1.csv` together into a dataframe and same for `files2.csv`

Comment: What should be done with the files from one folder? Should we combine them? Such that we end up with three dataframes?

Comment: No, I want to process the two files from each folder separately, so from each of the three folders I want to have two dataframe separately. Basically I want to loop through the three folders, go into the first one, import the two files, process them and export, then go to the next folder and to the same.

Comment: "saw some posts" please share the link, and share the codes you have tried. It should be something like `x <- list.files(..., full.names = TRUE)` then `myList <- lapply(x, read.csv)`, then apply some function for each data: `myOutput <- lapply(myList, function(i) dosomething(i))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
path = # set path accordingly, ~ "C:\User\Files\" 
file_paths = unlist(lapply(
  file.path(path, paste0("Data", 1L:3L)), # Data1, Data2, Data3
  \(x) { list.files(path = x, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE) }))
list2env(lapply(setNames(file_paths, basename(file_paths)), read.csv), 
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
# rm(path, file_paths)
```

which assumes all files have different names.

Disclaimer: I am working on mac0S and suspect that `file.path()` is 0S-agnostic.

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this:

```
files1 <- list.files(path = "C:\\User\\Files\\",
                    pattern = "file1.csv", 
                    recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
files2 <- list.files(path = "C:\\User\Files\\",
                    pattern = "file2.csv", 
                    recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

myfiles1 = lapply(files1, read.csv)
myfiles2 = lapply(files2, read.csv)


i = 1:length(myfiles1)

fn <- function(i) {
  
  dfFiles1 = myfiles1[[i]]
  
  dfFiles2 = myfiles2[[i]]
}
```